# How to integrate eclipse editor with my java desktop application designed in fxml?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, fxml

I need to access eclipse editor (where I can code) through my java desktop application designed in java fxml. is it possible?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: in image added,in my page i have access eclipse button,on clicking that button i need eclipse editor to open in my application only and i should be able to code in eclipse from my application only

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to "encapsulate" a windows application inside another one.

Comment: Eclipse editors are Eclipse plugins and only run in an 3.x compatibiliy mode Eclipse RCP using SWT. You can't use them in plain Java apps.